# Scheme: number to string, string to list

Tags: scheme, racket

I'd like to easily create a list of digits from an input number using Scheme's `number->string` and `string->list` functions.

This will code create the list of digits I want, but with one problem: `#\` will precede each digit:

```
(define input 1234)

(define (digit-list input)
    (string->list (number->string input))
)
```

Running `digit-list` on `input` yields:

```
(#\1  #\2  #\3  #\4 )
```

How can I generate this digit list without the `#\` preceding each digit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The preceding `#\` is scheme syntax for a character. You can convert each character to a number by first making it a `string`, then using `string->number`:

```
(number? (string->number (string #\1)))
=> #t
```

You can [`compose`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html?q=compose#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._compose%29%29) these two procedures, and `map` them onto your list as follows:

```
(map (compose string->number string)
     (string->list (number->string 1234)))
=> '(1 2 3 4)
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! For some reason, the compose function was not defined in my environment but using the link you gave, I could find it: (define (compose f g)
    (lambda (x)
      (f (g x)))) and it worked!